# Element 'a' cannot be nested inside element 'iframe'

Tags: vb.net, html, webbrowser-control

I am working a WebBowser project in Visual Studio 2015 that embeds a part of their functionality inside another website adding a html file. It runs without warnings using the Run Code snippet of stackoverflow but if I run it in Visual Studio 2015, it runs ok it but I get with these warnings:

- 200px is not a valid value of attribute width
- 461px is not a valid value of attribute height
- Element a cannot be nested inside element iframe

html Code:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Stock Quotes</title>
<style type="text/css">
    body {
     margin-left: 0px;
     margin-top: 0px;
     margin-right: 0px;
     margin-bottom: 0px;
     background-color: Gray;
    }
</style> 
</head>
<body>
    <iframe align="top" allowtransparency="true" marginwidth="0" 
            marginheight="0" hspace="0" vspace="0" frameborder="0" 
            scrolling="no" 
            src="http://api.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.0/GOOG,MSFT,ORCL,IBM/badge;quote/HTML?AppID=IEw2Pos2SwyGn532s_VbTecq4mIL&sig=BPVwexNv5yP8zim6MxBootdHqJw-&t=1256412813067" 
            width="200px" height="461px">
                <a href="http://finance.yahoo.com">Yahoo! Finance</a>
                <a href="http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=GOOG">Quote for GOOG</a>
    </iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `width` and `height` attributes do not take units (except `%`). Therefore:

```
... width="200" height="461" ...
```

For the second problem: The error is quite clear. You cannot have an `<a>` tag within an iframe. You are only allowed to have text inside it. For more details, see [here](https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/the-iframe-element.html#iframe-content-model).

Comment: Fixed all. Thank you.